# How do I access files from the resources folder in my RubyMotion code?

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have some data files in the resources/ folder for my Rubymotion project. How do I access them in the code? Accessing them without a path, is not working.

e.g. 
I have a file in resources/ called schema.json

Here's the code I am using:

```
NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile("schema.json") <--- returns nil
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
path = NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource("schema", ofType:"json")
NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path)
```

Comment: After which, how do you query it? How can you store it into a Hash?

Comment: You can use a JSON parser. I use BubbleWrap (https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap)